# Take maximum or minimum of a list in sass (scss)

Tags: list, sass, max, min

How can I take the maximum (or minimum) of a list in Sass (scss)?

`max(arg1, arg2, ...)` only takes separate arguments, not a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can expand elements of a list into arguments with the `...` operator:

`max($foo-list...)` will give you the maximum value of the list

Example:

```
$foo-list: 2px, 3px, 5px;
$max-of-list: max(foo-list...) // 5px
```